# Integral of the square of the integral of a function in $L^1 \cap L^2(S^1 \times \mathbb{R})$

Tags: real-analysis, integration, measure-theory

Suppose that I have a function $f: S^1 \times \mathbb{R} \to [0,+\infty]$, which is in $L^1(S^1 \times \mathbb{R}) \cap L^2(S^1 \times \mathbb{R})$. I am wondering about the integral $$I := \int_{S^1} \left( \int_{\mathbb{R}} f(t,x)dx \right)^2 dt.$$**Can I conclude that this integral is finite, and, better yet, can I estimate it in terms of $||f||_{L^1(S^1 \times \mathbb{R})}$ and $||f||_{L^2(S^1 \times \mathbb{R})}$?** I don't consider the spaces $S^1$ and $\mathbb{R}$ of vital importance - the only important thing is that $S^1$ has finite measure and $\mathbb{R}$ has infinite measure. I couldn't really make much progress on this, the best thing I could do is try to think of an example where $I$ would be infinite and come up with $f(x,t) = \frac{1}{2}e^{-x}\frac{1}{\sqrt{t}}$ (where I replaced $S^1$ by $[0,1]$, but I'm sure a similar example could be given for $S^1$ too). However, this $f$ is not in $L^2([0,1] \times \mathbb{R})$.

Comment: You mean simultaneously by both norms? Like controlling $I$ by a function of both norms?

Comment: @Shashi Yes, exactly.

Comment: then I don't know. But it's a good question!

Comment: @Shashi Anything you know is helpful, this is kind of an open-ended question. If you got a bound that only depends on one of the norms, that would in fact be even better!

Comment: yeah I implicitly meant that as well. But, no I don't know anything, but I can tell you that you cannot bound it with a contant times the 1-norm. That's all I know. Good luck!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's consider a slightly simpler scenario: Let $E=(0,1)\times(0,\infty)$ with area measure. For $(t,x)\in E,$ define

$$f(t,x) = \frac{1}{1+tx^2}.$$

Looks to me like $f\in (L^1\cap L^2)(E).$ What do you get for

$$\int_0^1 \left (\int_0^\infty f(t,x)\,dx\right )^2 \,dt?$$

Comment: Yep, $+\infty$! The square of the inner integral becomes $\frac{\pi^2}{4} \frac{1}{t}.$ This wasn't the answer I was hoping for, but probably the one I was expecting. Thanks!